# How to make a normalized table of adults and children?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

adults may have zero or more nephews and nieces. children may have zero or more aunts and uncles. How can this model be normalized if all adults and children are stored in one table?

this was a test question i got wrong and would like clarification on. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this a multi choice question?  If not, can you provide what you feel is the answer and/or why it is incorrect?

Comment: also.. I'm not thinking of a method of having all informaiton in a single table without duplicating some data, this seems like a many to many relationship which could not really be represented in a single table in a normalized fashion.  At least not a way that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Kritner lol thats almost word for word what i wrote and i got 0 points from the prof. Is my reason wrong or something?

"This is a many to many relationship that cannot be all in the same table b/c the table would need multiple primary keys"

Comment: now that i look at it, i suppose it would be more appropriate to say it would violate 3nf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's similar to how question is worded, I'm wondering if it's partially a trick question.

> all adults and children are stored in one table

That is to say, all of the people's information needs to be in one table, but the relationship between them does not necessarily have to be?

```
Person
---
personId PK
gender
dateOfBirth
firstName
lastName

PersonRelationship
---
id PK -- not really needed, i just like simple primary keys
personId FK -- always the elder
descendantId FK -- always the youngling
```

Find nieces/nephews of a specific person:

```
select *
from person p
inner join personRelationship pr on p.personId = pr.personId
inner join person descendant on pr.descendantId = descendant.personId
where p.personId = 1
```

find aunts/uncles of a specific person:

```
select *
from person p
inner join personRelationship pr on p.personId = pr.descendantId
inner join person ancestor on pr.personId = ancestor.personId
where p.personId = 3
```

So as an example with data you could have.

```
Person
1, 'm', null, 'uncle', 'tom'
2, 'f', null, 'aunt', 'danielle'
3, 'm', null, 'nephew', 'realName'

PersonRelationship
1, 1, 3 -- 1 is a ancestor to 3, 3 is a descendant of 1
2, 2, 3 -- 2 is a ancestor to 3, 3 is a descendant of 2
```

Comment: Oh I see, so i could create it with a bridge. Thanks!!

Comment: hopefully that helps... that's the only thing I can think of that could be, somewhat of a trick question :O

Answer (score 1):

If you are investing on this adult and child relation as an important relation in your analysis and also need a normalized design then you need to consider them as two different entities in two different tables related together via a third table. Or keep all adults and children in one table and their relations in another table.

If you do it by just one table then you might have to keep several values in just one data field for a record at the table and that means a non-normalized design and you need string processing to separate those values when they are needed.